# Thinkpad X131e WiFi faulty

Tags: networking, thinkpad

I just got a thinkpad x131e and installed Ubuntu MATE 17.10 on it which worked well. 
However now that it's up and running it says it is connected to wifi but no application can load anything from the internet including the router/modem settings through the defalt gateway.
I can tell this is a problem with the wifi because pages load when my device is connected through an ethernet cable.

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.

Comment: Please log in to edit your post - you can ask mods to merge your accounts. Also, please put solutions in the answer section, not in the question